# Add a spinner to a row cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an editable table.
The table can be upgraded any time. There is a button in the last row of each column. I have a web gif that is it shows a progress bar spinner.
What I am currently doing is to show that image whenever user clicks update in a row at the corner of the page.
What Id like to do is that I'd like to replace the last cell (which has the button) with that spinner image and once the upload completes I can have my button back. I'm using ajax for asynchronous upload.

I tried to do the following:

```
rowcell.html();
rowcell.append('#spinner');
```

But it is not working. Because when I do

```
$('#spinner').show();
```

both spinners become visible. Does anyone have a better method of solving this?

Comment: add a jsFiddle with your code.

Comment: Are you adding `#spinner` to every table row / cell? When using the hashtag, you are indicating an `ElementByID` and you may only use an ID once per page.

Comment: Oh yes! I realize my mistake. Should I add a class then for my spinner?

Comment: Actually it is working now.
Problem is though that I can't access the image in my js as  django does not allow it.
So I must declare it in my html. So I cant just add a new spinner every time.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you can use a selector on append. 
Try:

rowcell.append($('#spinner'));
or

$('#spinner').appendTo(rowcell);

Answer (score -1):

I would use jQuery selectors to make sure you get the right spinner. I'm not sure exactly how your HTML ends up. If you have a button in each row, you should be able to use the `.parent` selector to get the parent element of the button and then only target that element in your `.show` call.